# SalesForce, Collecting data and writing new data

Tags: salesforce

I am quite new to SalesForce and I have been researching about it. I was wondering how would I collect data from a quote sheet and create and organize the fields in a new org.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow At this site you are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing more research, if you have a problem you can post **what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/6676466).

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly comment, but I believe that my boss said that there is quite little to almost no coding involved for salesforce? It is mostly click and drag I believe he said.

What can I do to improve this question?

Comment: If there is just a little or no code then you can write what you have researched with clear explanation of what isn't working, so experts will give you a better solution of your problem.